# Trouble with Exception Classes

Tags: java, arrays, exception, joptionpane

I'm a student programmer, and am having problems on exception classes on an assignment that I have been working on for the past week or so. I've gotten most parts of it down. The main objective of the program is (Write a program to enter employee data, including SSN (Social Security Number) and salary into an array with maximum # of 100. Allow to enter less than 100 employees.) So far I have this.

```
package employee;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Employee extends Person //Employee derived from class : Person
{

private String SSN;
private double salary;


public Employee()  //Constructors
{
    super();
    SSN = "No social security number entered.";
    salary = 0.00;
}

public Employee(String initialName)
{
    super(initialName);
    SSN = "No social security number entered.";
    salary = 0.00;
}

public Employee(String initialName, String ssn)
{
    super(initialName);
    SSN = ssn;
    salary = 0.00;
}

public Employee(String initialName, String ssn, double pay)
{
    super(initialName);
    SSN = "No social security entered.";
    salary = pay;
}


@Override
public String getName() //Accessor Methods
{
    return name;
}

public String getSSN()
{
    return SSN;
}

public double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}

public void setName() //Mutator Methods
{
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee Name: ");
}

public void setSSN()
{

   boolean done = false;

    while(!done)
    {

        SSN = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Employee Social Security Number: ");

        String trim = SSN.trim();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Entered: " 
                                      + trim
                                      + "\n\nVALIDATING SOCIAL SECURITY NUMBER");

        SSNLengthException(trim);
        SSNCharacterException(trim);

        done = true;
    }
} 

private void SSNCharacterException(String trim) 
{
    boolean SSNCharacterException;
    if (SSNCharacterException)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

private void SSNLengthException(String trim) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


}
```

I am not really well versed when it comes to exception classes, and have tried If/Else, and Try/Catch for exceptions. Would i need a separate class as I've done for an exception, or will I have needed to initialize it within the main class? These are the 2 exception classes that needed to be done: 
(The program should use two exception class,
    one called: SSNLengthException
when SSN entered without 2 dashes and not 9 digits
    one called: SSNCharacterException
when SSN entered has non digits)

(I apologize for the messy format as this is my first time asking a question on here)

So far with the help, I was able to make the exception classes and define them. My question now is, as it is confusing from my professors notes and from all the questions I've seen on the site, is how would I specifically check for integer values. I've seen some questions like mine being answered with `parseInt`or to change the string to int. Maybe it is because I am using JOptionPane that I am facing a lot more difficulty but my professor wants it in that form. Are there any recommended ways to define an exception for that? or would that need to be defined in the main class, and the exception is to be used to tell the program what to do in that instance? Sorry for the repeated questions, I am just having a lot of troubles with Exception classes. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: `SSNCharacterException` and `SSNLengthException` should be the names of classes, not the names of methods.  You should put each of them in their own file of source code.  Both of them should extend `Exception`.

Comment: Hint: there are 3 parts to excpetions... (1) define the Exception class, e.g "class SSNCharacterException extends Exception..."  (2) throw it when you detect an error, e.g "if (...input contains invalid chars) throw new SSNCharacterException ("invalid character")"  (3) catch it and decide what to do, e.g. print an error and rery.